# How can I change numbers font in time library?

Tags: python, time, numbers, bots, telethon

I wanna change the numbers font in %H & %M with the me numbers and in the output time the me numbers be shown instead of usual numbers font(1,...,9). I'll be so glad if anybody who knows what's the solution, help me and solve my problem. Thanks a lot.

```
import time
me = (₀, ₁, ₂, ₃, ₄, ₅, ₆, ₇, ₈, ₉, ₁₀)
HM = time.strftime("%H:%M")
```

Comment: In Python and most other programming languages, digits (number characters) — like all other characters — doesn't have fonts associated with them, they're just Unicode code points (in Python 3.x).

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `dict`, then you will be able to replace the digits with your own choices.

```
import time
dictionary = {
    '0' : '₀', '1' : '₁', '2' : '₂', '3' : '₃', '4': '₄',
    '5' : '₅', '6' : '₆', '7' : '₇', '8' : '₈', '9' : '₉' 
}

HM = time.strftime("%H:%M")
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    HM = HM.replace(key,value)
```

Comment: Although this will work, It's highly inefficient to loop through the dictionary and replace the value of `HM` 10 times.

Answer (score 2):

Text characters don't have a font associated with them in Python, they're just unicode code points. However what it sounds like you're really wanting to do is change the actual digit characters in the string that `time.strftime()` returns into another set.

The most efficient way to do this would probably be to create a translation table that maps the digit characters to those you would like to use using the [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) **class** method, and then pass it as the argument to the [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) **instance** method to do the conversion.

Here's how to do it. **Note** that you only have to build the translation table once, it can used over-and-over, many times.

```
import string
import time

me = '₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉'
xlate_tbl = str.maketrans(string.digits, me)  # Create translation table.

HM = time.strftime("%H:%M")
print(HM)
print(HM.translate(xlate_tbl))  # Translate result.
```

Sample output:

```
17:42
₁₇:₄₂
```